# How to convert unix timestamp to UTC 0 format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm using the following string to convert from unixtimestamp to date time

```
date_format(from_unixtime(timestamp),'%Y-%m-%eT%k:%i:%s') AS 'Fecha'
```

It works but I need the time in UTC 0. There's any way t do it in the SQL request?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'UTC 0'? Unix time stamps are UTC by definition.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yes, but when you use from_unixtime and date_format it will format to the local time.

Comment: So I repeat: What do you mean by 'UTC 0'.  Do you just mean UTC?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I'm at UTC -3 and I don't want the local time I want the UTC without any add o subtraction from the UTC time, that why I say UTC 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to do this:

```
set time_zone="UTC";
select from_unixtime(1687412703,'%Y-%m-%eT%k:%i:%s') AS 'Fecha';
-- you may want to set the session time zone back to it's original setting after this.
```

However, this will only work well if your server is now, and has always been, set up properly with the correct time zone. If the server configuration is wrong, your time stampswon't be accurate and the results can be unpredictable.

Comment: I solved by adding 3600*3 to the original timestamp. date_format(from_unixtime(timestamp+(3600*3)),'%Y-%m-%eT%k:%i:%s') AS 'Fecha' I know is not the most elegant but it works. Tomorrow I will try your solution just to learn something new because at this moment I just closed the server connection to my PC.

Comment: Does this apply to my current connection or to all the server? I don't want the server time setting. Currently MySQL is set it to SYSTEM.

Comment: This is session-specific. You can set the time zone for the whole server with `set global time_zone = 'UTC';

Comment: Ok, I just wondering if is safe to do that because there's a lot of PC's and servers connected to that database and I don't want to mess up.

Comment: @E_Blue If you aren't sure, don't do it. Build a test server and do things there first, or work outside business hours so that you can roll back changes if you need to.